# Can var_dump a string but can not echo the string

Tags: url, echo, var-dump

I meet a trouble with string.
I use file_get_contents($url) to get content of a website.

```
$content = tile_get_contents($url);
$arrTmp = explode('>',$content);
var_dump (trim( $arrTmp[100]) ) => result is: string '<td width="33.3333333333%" valign="top"'
echo trim( $arrTmp[100]); => nothing.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your sample seems to be incomplete

you define $arr

where does $arrTmp comes from?

what is $i? is it defined?

whats between the var_dump and echo?

and whats the purpose of this Action?

EDIT:
just tested:

```
$url = 'http://w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp'; 
$ctx = stream_context_create(array('http'=> array( 'timeout' => 60 ) )); 
$content = file_get_contents($url, false, $ctx); 
$arrTmp = explode('>',$content);
for($i = 0; $i < count($arrTmp); $i++)
{ 
    echo '<br />'; 
    echo 'Res->'.htmlspecialchars(trim($arrTmp[$i])); 
}
```

result:

```
Res-><!DOCTYPE html
Res-><html lang="en-US"
Res-><head
Res-><title
```

and so on ...

maybe a server-setup-issue? but i have no idea what it could be at your side ...

Comment: Thank you!
I edited the content of my question.
I explode content of a web site by '>', then I want to echo every value of the array, but I can not show them by echo function, then I can show it by var_dump function.

Comment: i think preg_split would be better, but your described behavior is really strange ... i think you've checked the source of the page with your test-Output (because if the browser interpretes the "<td.." nothing will Show up. what if you try echo "---".trim($arrTmp[100])."---"; ?

Comment: That is my code:

    $url = 'http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp';
    $ctx = stream_context_create(array('http'=>
                                    array(
                                        'timeout' => 60, // 60 Seconds = 1 Minutes
                                    )
                                ));
    $content = file_get_contents($url, false, $ctx);
    $arrTmp = explode('>',$content);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($arrTmp); $i++){
        var_dump($arrTmp[$i]);
        echo '<br>';
        echo 'Res->'.($arrTmp[$i]);
    }
Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much! :D
That is all things I need. :)